# Grafana Variable to select Azure resource group and resource select dynamically

Tags: azure, grafana, grafana-variable

I am creating Grafana Variable where has resource group and resource should select dynamically, How can we achieve  this in grafana variable or any other way it is possible?

Screenshot is below [image]

In above screen shot I need to select all resource group within in subscription and Namespace I choose VirtualMachine and select resource should dynamically select any VM within selected subscription. It is only allowing to select one resource group and one resource.

Is it possible to achieve this ?